# Typescript : TS7017 Index signature of object type implicitly has an 'any' type in a loop

Tags: typescript

I am having the following code in typescript :

```
export class Custom {
     [k: string]: any // Index Signature

     // parameters example
     // let o:Object = {"blah":1, "foo": "lol"}
     // let arr: Array<string> = ["blah", "foo"]
    constructor(o: Object, p: Array<string>)
     for(let prop of arr) {
        let p: any = (<any>o)[prop]
        if (p !== undefined) {
            this[prop] = p
        }
      }
}
```

I keep having `TS7017 Index signature of object type implicitly has an 'any' type` on `this[prop] = p`

Thanks !

Edit : Adding the index signature solved my problem.

Comment: What version of Typescript are you using ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I prevent the error "Index signature of object type implicitly has an 'any' type" when compiling typescript with noImpicitAny flag enabled?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32968332/how-do-i-prevent-the-error-index-signature-of-object-type-implicitly-has-an-an)

Comment: I did update the case, so it's not a duplicate of that one anymore.

Comment: What is `this` in `this[prop]` ?

Comment: I have added the full code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> TS7017 Index signature of object type implicitly has an 'any' type

Whatever `this` is in that code, it does not have an index signature (so implicit any).

## Quick Fix

- Switch off `noImplicitAny` till you get more comfortable working with TypeScript.

Comment: I am gonna edit my post to include this, which is only a simple class.
However, I'd be very interested into seeing how to create an index signature.

Comment: Thanks the Index Signature fixed my problem.