# getting error Index signature of object type implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: angular

I am using Angular Version 2.1.0 and writing one of service to load a component dynamically.

I an getting below error, how to resolve it?

**Error TS7017  Index signature of object type implicitly has an 'any' type.**

```js
import { Injectable, ComponentFactoryResolver, ApplicationRef, ElementRef, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

import { SpinnerComponent } from '../components/blockui/blockui.component';


@Injectable()
export class SpinnerService {
    spinnerComp: ViewContainerRef;
    constructor(private componentLoader: ComponentFactoryResolver, private appRef: ApplicationRef) { }

    public start() {
        //error in this line?
        let elementRef: ElementRef = this.appRef['_rootComponents'][0].location;

        return this.startInside(elementRef, null);
    }

    public startInside(elementRef: ElementRef, anchorName: string) {

        let spinnerRef = (!anchorName) ?
            this.componentLoader.resolveComponentFactory.call(SpinnerComponent, elementRef) :
            this.componentLoader.resolveComponentFactory.call(SpinnerComponent, elementRef, anchorName);

        spinnerRef.then((compRef: ViewContainerRef) => {
            this.spinnerComp = compRef;
        });
    }

    public stop() {
        if (this.spinnerComp) {
            this.spinnerComp.detach();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It appears `this.appRef['_rootComponents'][0].location` isn't of type `ElementRef`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It tells you that when you do `this.appRef['_rootComponents']` it does not know what the type of the property is and assumes `any` by default which is treated as an error according to settings in tsc configuration file. Please read [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32968332/how-do-i-prevent-the-error-index-signature-of-object-type-implicitly-has-an-an) for more details and possible solutions.