# Cannot Restart node Server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, typescript

I am currently learning Angular 2. To setup the environment, I installed NodeJS and used the Angular Quickstart process from Github (http://github.com/angular/quickstart). After that, opened GitBash and navigated to an empty folder in my C:\ Drive and cloned Quickstart there, as instructed. I installed the npm server thingy, using "npm install", and then I started the server that Angular runs on, using "npm start". Everything was fine until I ended the process, using CTRL + C. When I attempted to restart the server, using "npm start" again, in GitShell, I got errors:

[From GitShell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1riQ.png)

Is there a proper process to terminating, or restarting the server? Am I using the wrong command?

Comment: what error it is giving

Comment: Do a `git checkout .` and try again

Comment: I tried "git checkout" and I am still getting the same error. @Ananth

Comment: Click the "From GitShell" link in the Question Description @shikharbansal

Comment: This previous stackoverflow answer may help you. Looks like you need to give a type to your "i" parameter (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32968332/how-do-i-prevent-the-error-index-signature-of-object-type-implicitly-has-an-an)

Comment: Thanks @alfredo . The type exception was the problem.

Comment: @GeraldMatthews You are welcome. I'm glad it's all working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant line is a TypeScript compiler error:

`error TS7006:  Parameter i implicity has any type`.

There is a variable called `i` that is declared without a Type annotation, and Typescript wasn't able to infer the type.

Your TypeScript config has `noImplicitAny=true`, which causes TypeScript to treat that as an error.

To progress you could:

- add a type annotation to the `i` variable
- disable `noImplicitAny` in `tsconfig.json`

See [TypeScript compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) for more detail about `noImplicitAny`.