# How to create class based on string

Tags: node.js, typescript, constructor

How to create a Class based on given String?

I tried this code but it doesn't work.

```
public create(className: string): ISports {
   // className = "Baseball";
   return new global[className]();
}
```

I keep getting this error.

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'Global' has no
>   index signature.

Comment: Try `return new global[className : string]();` [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32968332/how-do-i-prevent-the-error-index-signature-of-object-type-implicitly-has-an-an)

Comment: Or in `tscconfig.json` add `"noImplicitAny": false`

Comment: did not work guys