# TypeScript: How to handle this case without 'any' type declaration? Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'Object' has no index signature

Tags: javascript, typescript, iteration

I'm having JSON data source as like below,

```
var datasource = [{name: 'x', age: 20, address: 'yyyy'},
                  {name: 's', age: 30, address: 'zzzz'}]
```

in this fields(name, age, address) will be dynamically changed as per the user. Here i want to iterating the records and its values.

I am trying like this and facing exception,

```
let keys: Object[] = Object.keys(datasource[0]);
let dlen: number = datasource.length as number;
while (dlen--) {
    let kLn: number = keys.length;
    while (kLn--) {
        let key: string = keys[kLn] as string;
        let isPropContains: boolean = false;
        let value: string;
        if(datasource[dlen][key]) {
             isPropContains = true;
             value = datasource[dlen][key] as string;
        }
    }
}
```

Here, how can i access object property (datasource[dlen]**[key]**) like we accessing in javascript index type?

**Note: I want to achieve this without using type 'any' and 'eval' in typescript. Need strongly typed.**

I have checked this [How do I dynamically assign properties to an object in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710905/how-do-i-dynamically-assign-properties-to-an-object-in-typescript) but it doest satisfied my requirement. Because they using 'any' type, i want to achieve without using 'any' or 'eval'.

Comment: If you had simply pasted the error into any half-decent search engine, you would have found the linked question and its answers.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I have edited my question. I need to access object property like index signature, without using 'any' type. Already i have checked that post, it won't help me.

Comment: Applying [the first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32968953/157247) to that question to your code: https://pastebin.com/cMg2WdG9 The only trick was that `age` is `number` and the other two are string. The playground (with the `noImplicitAny` option enabled) has no complaints about that code (too big to link, but if you copy-and-paste and set the option...).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: In my case datasource is not static, So 'age' and 'name' is just an example that i provided. Properties may differ with different type. This is dynamic. So i can't create interface for that datasource.

Comment: So you have a datasource with a varying structure, and you want to apply typechecking to it. I don't see how that works logically...? If you can't define a structure for it, how are you going to apply typechecking for it?

Comment: Sorry @T.J.Crowder. I just want to know weather property available to that object and i need to access that value. Value will be number | string | Date.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163315/discussion-between-pranath-and-t-j-crowder).

Comment: Then you'll need to do what's in the pastebin above (minus the actual fields, e.g.: https://pastebin.com/F1LS5Saa). `string|number|Date` is better than `any` for typechecking I suppose! :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Before that, I can not access the property as like array index signature. It throws exception " Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'Object' has no index signature"
https://ibb.co/fqzoRm

Comment: Please look closely at the code I linked. `Object` isn't used, and TypeScript doesn't have any complaints about that code (even with the noImplicitAny option set).

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder. Your trick works for me.