# Dictionary in TS

Tags: javascript, typescript

I would like to make simple dictionary in TS.

It's works but I getting error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{ 'The ticket field is required.': string; 'The selected ticket is invalid.': string; }' has no index signature.

My code:

```
const translation = {
  'The ticket field is required.': 'Musisz podać numer swojego biletu.',
  'The selected ticket is invalid.': 'Wybrany bilet jest nieprawidłowy.'
};

this.error = translation['The ticket field is required.'];
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32968332/how-do-i-prevent-the-error-index-signature-of-object-type-implicitly-has-an-an

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I prevent the error "Index signature of object type implicitly has an 'any' type" when compiling typescript with noImplicitAny flag enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32968332/how-do-i-prevent-the-error-index-signature-of-object-type-implicitly-has-an-an)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare the value `translation` like this:

```
const translation = {
  'The ticket field is required.': 'Musisz podać numer swojego biletu.',
  'The selected ticket is invalid.': 'Wybrany bilet jest nieprawidłowy.'
};
```

You are omitting the type declaration. That means `translation` is typed *implicitly*. If you would declare the respective type explicitly, your const declaration would look like this:

```
const translation:
{
    //This is the type declaration
    'The ticket field is required.': string;
    'The selected ticket is invalid.': string;
} = {
    //This is the value
    'The ticket field is required.': 'Musisz podać numer swojego biletu.',
    'The selected ticket is invalid.': 'Wybrany bilet jest nieprawidłowy.'
};
```

Since you have declared your value as `const`, the compiler *knows* that the only properties are the ones you have provided.

When you now are accessing your type like...

```
this.error = translation['The ticket field is required.'];
```

...you are using it as a *mapped type*. Since the compiler does not see (because it does not check) that the key you have provided matches one of the property names of the inferred type, it will assume that the type of the expression `translation['The ticket field is required.']` is of type `any`. Since this is an implicit `any` and you are in strict mode, you get the error.

The simple solution is to provide explicit typing for your value:

```
const translation: { [key: string]: string } = {
    'The ticket field is required.': 'Musisz podać numer swojego biletu.',
    'The selected ticket is invalid.': 'Wybrany bilet jest nieprawidłowy.'
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try to provide a type hint:

```
const translation = {
  'The ticket field is required.': 'Musisz podać numer swojego biletu.',
  'The selected ticket is invalid.': 'Wybrany bilet jest nieprawidłowy.'
} as { [index:string] : string };
```

Comment: Instead of casting, you can have it as the type: `const translation: { [index:string] : string }`