# TypeScript narrow down the keys of indexable type by its value types

Tags: typescript

Given we have a generic indexable type how can I retrieve only the types of its values to be able to narrow down to only some of the keys?

```
// imagine check is a function and its second argument only allows the property `a` as it's string and raise an error if 'b' is passed
const test2 = check({ a: 'string', b: 22 }, 'b'); // error only 'a' is allowed
const test2 = check({ a: 'str', b: 'str2' }, 'b'); // ok returns 'str2'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you can do this by using [conditional](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#conditional-types) and [mapped](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) types to extract just the keys of an object type `T` whose values match a value type `V`:

```
type KeysMatching<T, V> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends V ? K : never }[keyof T];
declare function check<T>(obj: T, k: KeysMatching<T, string>): string;

const test1 = check({ a: 'string', b: 22 }, 'b'); // error 
const test2 = check({ a: 'str', b: 'str2' }, 'b'); // ok
```

Hope that helps.  Good luck!