# Union type of Partial<CssStyleDeclaration> and dictionary causes typing issues with no implicit any flag

Tags: typescript, vue.js

As it is possible to set CSS variables using VueJS `v-bind:style` binding, I am trying to create a union type where the object passed to `v-bind:style` retains the typings for `CssStyleDelcaration` and yet is relaxed enough to accept an arbitrary property name:

```ts
type Dictionary<T> = { [key: string]: T };
type Nullable<T> = T | null;
type CssStyleObject =
  Partial<CSSStyleDeclaration> |
  Dictionary<Nullable<string>>;
```

An example of the implementation is as such ([see live code on TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Dictionary%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20T%20%7D%3B%0D%0Atype%20Nullable%3CT%3E%20%3D%20T%20%7C%20null%3B%0D%0Atype%20CssStyleObject%20%3D%20Partial%3CCSSStyleDeclaration%3E%20%7C%20Dictionary%3CNullable%3Cstring%3E%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20style%3A%20CssStyleObject%20%3D%20%7B%20%7D%3B%0D%0Astyle.backgroundColor%20%3D%20'red'%3B%0D%0Astyle%5B'--my-custom-css-property'%5D%20%3D%20'16px'%3B)):

```html
<!-- Template -->
<div v-bind:style="myStyle"></div>
```

```ts
// Component code
@Component
export default class MyComponent extends Vue {
  public get myStyle(): CssStyleObject {
    const style: CssStyleObject = { };
    style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    style['--my-custom-css-property'] = '16px';
  }
}
```

However, I get a type error when I have `noImplicitAny` flag enabled (a flag that I cannot be turned off because of a project-wide configuration), because TypeScript then complains about:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'CssStyleObject' has no index signature.

I've seen a proposed solution here: [How do I prevent the error "Index signature of object type implicitly has an 'any' type" when compiling typescript with noImplicitAny flag enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32968332/how-do-i-prevent-the-error-index-signature-of-object-type-implicitly-has-an-an), but I would love to avoid simply casting to `any`, if there is another viable solution possible.

The funny thing is, the error message goes away once I use a custom property name when assigning to the `style` variable:

```
const style: CssStyleObject = {
    '--foobar': '50%'
};
style.backgroundColor = 'red';
style['--my-custom-css-property'] = '16px';
```

[See the code above on TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Dictionary%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20T%20%7D%3B%0D%0Atype%20Nullable%3CT%3E%20%3D%20T%20%7C%20null%3B%0D%0Atype%20CssStyleObject%20%3D%20Partial%3CCSSStyleDeclaration%3E%20%7C%20Dictionary%3CNullable%3Cstring%3E%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20style%3A%20CssStyleObject%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20'--foobar'%3A%20'50%25'%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0Astyle.backgroundColor%20%3D%20'red'%3B%0D%0Astyle%5B'--my-custom-css-property'%5D%20%3D%20'16px'%3B).

I suspect that is because the type for `style` is then somehow modified to be simply `Dictionary<string>` instead of the union type, so no further errors will be thrown.

---

### Update and solution

So, it turns out that I inherently confused **intersection** and **union** types in TypeScript. In this case, the `CssStyleObject` is an intersection of `Partial<CSSStyleDeclaration>` *and* `Dictionary<Nullable<string>>`, so this should suffice:

```
type Dictionary<T> = { [key: string]: T };
type Nullable<T> = T | null;

// Use `&` for creating an intersection type!
type CssStyleObject =
  Partial<CSSStyleDeclaration> &
  Dictionary<Nullable<string>>;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, the current behavior of your code is because the way discriminated union type works. `CSSStyleDeclaration` doesn't have a index signature while Dictionary does. So when you add a custom property in declaration, the type is inferred as `Dictionary`.

Secondly, you shouldn't use union type if you want add a index to a existing type. You should use intersection type instead. That is said, `CssStyleObject` is a `CSSStyleDeclaration` and has a index signature, but not a object which is either `CssStyleObject` or has a index signature

Lastly, here is working code

```js
type CssStyleObject = Partial<CSSStyleDeclaration> & Record<string, string | null>
// or 
interface CssStyleObject extends Partial<CSSStyleDeclaration> {
    [key: string]: string | null
}
```