# How to access a property of an object using the bracket notation in TypeScript strict mode

Tags: typescript

The following TypeScript sample code shows an error `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{one: number; two: number;}' has no index signature` in the line `const one = obj[prop];` in strict mode.

The compiler allows the line `const two = obj[propName];`, so I cannot understand why the error is shown or how to generally speaking access a property of an object using the bracket notation.

```
const obj = { one: 1, two: 2 };

const props = { one: 'one', two: 'two' };

// it is not possible add or change any properties in the props object 
props.zero = 'zero';
props.one = 1;

// prop has the type string
const prop = props.one;

// using the bracket notation fails with the following error message:
// Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{one: number; two: number;}' has no index signature.
// const prop: string
const one = obj[prop];

// this works because propName is of type 'two'
const propName = 'two';
const two = obj[propName];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I prevent the error "Index signature of object type implicitly has an 'any' type" when compiling typescript with noImplicitAny flag enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32968332/how-do-i-prevent-the-error-index-signature-of-object-type-implicitly-has-an-an)

Comment: What is the `target` you are using? It seems to be working fine without errors.

Comment: @JayantVarshney Did you test in strict mode? (noImplicitAny, strictNullChecks)

Comment: @doberkofler yes, I am using `es6`

Comment: @JayantVarshney Sorry. Not strict mode in JS but strict compiler settings in TypeScript

Comment: Right @doberkofler

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{one: number; two: number;}' has no index signature

Your object has no index signature, it has two named properties.

> The compiler allows the line const two = obj['two'];

It allows the names of your properties, that's why obj['two'] and obj['one'] will work.

> and the const prop is a string, so I cannot understand why the error is shown

Because a string can have much more values that just 'one' or 'two' and so the compiler cannot ensure, your `object[myString]` call will work. It's only valid for two defined string values.

> how to generally speaking access a property of an object using the bracket notation.

This would work:

```
 const prop: 'one' | 'two' = 'one';
 const test = obj[prop]
```

You say: prop has value 'one' or 'two' and so the compiler knows your obj[prop] will always be valid.

or

```
 class Example {
   one: string;
   two: string;
 }
 const prop: keyof Example = 'one';
 const test = obj[prop];
```

Here `keyof(ClassName)` tells the compiler, that your prop var will have an existing property name of `Example`.

The above examples assume, that you have an object where only the properties named 'one' and 'two' are valid. If you want to use your object in a "dictionary style", tell typescript about that and add an index signature:

```
 const obj: {[key:string]: string;} = { one: 'one' };
 const text = obj[myString];
```

Now obj allows every string values as key.

Comment: Thank you. I starting to understand. The problem is not the fact that I use the using the bracket notation by itself but rather the expression that I'm using. What still confuses me a little, is why the compiler does not consider the fact that my props object actually only consists of two properties that contain the property names used in obj?

Comment: `props.one`is of type string (that's simply the default when you assign a value without specifying a type as you do it with `{one: 'one' }`). You didn't tell the compiler more about it.

Comment: shouldn't it be `const prop: keyof Example  = 'one';`?

Comment: Correct, but in `const propName = 'two'` propName is also just of string and the compiler seems to accept it. This is exactly what got me lost.

Comment: @doberkofler: According to my VS hints, `const t = 'one'` results in `t: 'one'`. So, no - it's not a string. (While `const o = {one: 'one'}` results in `o.one: string`.

Comment: @ChristophLütjen You are absolutely right. I overlooked that type type of `propName` in `const propName = 'two'` is actually `'two'`. What I still do not understand is why TypeScript cannot infer the same information when using the properties of the `props` object?

Comment: thanks mann @ChristophLütjen ! you saved my day

Comment: The reason the example code doesn't work is that the type of `props` is inferred (not explicit) and for convenience it is inferred to `{one: string, two: string}` because usually that's what we mean. Not specific strings, any string. The compiler can be told you mean these exact strings by adding "as const": `const props = { one: 'one', two: 'two' } as const;`.
Now the type of props.one is `"one"` and you can use it to index `obj` directly.

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned, the inferred type of `props` is `{one: string, two: string}`. This means `props.one` could be any string (even though we see it is "one"), so when you write `obj[props.one]` what you're really accessing is `obj[string]` which may not be allowed.

If you made your props an explicit type, you could get around it:
`type Props = {one: "one", two: "two"}`, and then use it:
`const props: Props = {one: "one", two: "two"}`

This way the type of `props` is not inferred, and the explicit type of the values is "one" or "two".

But that's annoying to write when what you really want to say is that `props` is these exact values. You can tell the compiler not to be clever about the type it infers and use the exact values you specified with `as const`:

```
const obj = { one: 1, two: 2 };
const props = { one: 'one', two: 'two' } as const;

const prop = props.one;

const one = obj[prop];
```

Now the compiler knows that `prop` has the exact value "one" instead of any `string`. So it is allowed.

Answer (score -1):

Particularly I'm fan of strong type, but 
`const obj: any` should be ok.

```
interface test { 
    one: string;
    two: string;
}

const props: test = { one: 'one', two: 'two' }; // {one: string, two: string}
const obj: any = {one: 1, two: 2}; // {one: number, two: number}


const two = obj['two']; // number

const prop = props.one; // string

const one = obj[prop];
```

Enum Solution

```
enum numbers {
    one = 1,
    two = 2
}

const oneStr = numbers[numbers.one];
const one = numbers[oneStr];
```

Comment: I understand that using a type any on obj would solve this error but this would also completely remove any type checking on obj itself and therefore be quite the opposite of a string typing. Maybe I just did not understand and you could elaborate on your solution.

Comment: Using `any` completely defeats the purpose of using TypeScript.. Yes, there are times when you kind of need `any`, but generally speaking, if you are just going to use `any` everywhere, just write es6 and ditch typescript because you're using it wrong.

Comment: My idea is not refactoring the whole post, is only solve the compilation issue. I prefer using strong type. Indeed it is possible create a solution only using `enums`, but the original post can be an simplified scenery.  I'm trying to follow the rule, if some ask A I'm answer A, in some case suggest B.

Comment: @AgustinEloyBarrios ok, but how would you then solve this with an `enum`?