# angular strict mode throws and error as `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings

code :

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(ref => {

  if (window['ngRef']) {
    window['ngRef'].destroy();
  }
  window['ngRef'] = ref;

 
}).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

the above code form `main.ts` file from angular.  how to fix in this case?
what is the correct way to update this code?

Comment: It's saying you can't access a property on an object using the square brackets which are only used when you need to index into an array

Comment: agree. how to fix this? any idea please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to **any** type

```
const _window = window as any;
if (_window['ngRef']) {
  _window.destroy();
}
_window['ngRef'] = ref;
```

The above code is used by webpack for hot reloads to ensure Angular destroys itself on hot reloads.

Read about the typescript error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55959430/11719787)

BTW if you don't want to use **any**, but want to use strict type instead, then you can extend `window`'s type

```
//This will tell typescript that window also contains ngRef property
type windowExtended = Window & typeof globalThis & {
  ngRef: NgModuleRef<AppModule>;
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .then(ref => {
    const _window = window as windowExtended;
    if (_window['ngRef']) {
      _window['ngRef'].destroy();
    }
    _window['ngRef'] = ref;

  })
```

Comment: If window['ngRef'] doesn't exist because ngModule wasn't injected, there is no sense to do, if will never validate

Answer (score 0):

I've given a spin to Sameer answer.

```js
type WindowExtended = Window & typeof globalThis & {
  ngRef: ApplicationRef;
}

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent)
  .then((ref: ApplicationRef) => ensureDestroyOnHotReload(ref))
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));

function ensureDestroyOnHotReload(ref: ApplicationRef): void {
  let { ngRef } = window as WindowExtended
  if (ngRef) {
    ngRef.destroy()
  }
  ngRef = ref
}
```