# How to configure Knex.ts in TypeScript project?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typescript, knex.js

I am trying to configure Knexfile in TypeScript. I created `knexfile.ts` with `knex init -x ts`:

```
const defaults = {
  client: 'postgresql',
  connection: {
    host: DB_HOST,
    user: DB_USER,
    password: DB_PASSWORD,
    database: DB_DATABASE
  },
  pool: {
    min: 2,
    max: 10
  },
  migrations: {
    tableName: 'knex_migrations'
  }
};

const knexConfig = {
  local: {
    client: 'sqlite3',
    connection: {
      filename: './dev.sqlite3'
    }
  },

  development: {
    ...defaults,
    debug: true,
    useNullAsDefault: true
  },

  production: {
    ...defaults
  }
};

export default knexConfig;
```

And then I create `knex.ts` file to make connection:

```
import Knex, { Config } from 'knex';
import knexConfig from '../utils/knexfile';
import { NODE_ENV } from '../utils/config';

// Set environment from `.env`
const knex = Knex(knexConfig[NODE_ENV]);

export default knex;
```

But I got an error at `(knexConfig[NODE_ENV])`, saying that:

```
(alias) const NODE_ENV: string
import NODE_ENV
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ local: { client: string; connection: { filename: string; }; }; development: { debug: boolean; useNullAsDefault: boolean; client: string; connection: { host: string; user: string; password: string; database: string; }; pool: { ...; }; migrations: { ...; }; }; production: { ...; }; }'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ local: { client: string; connection: { filename: string; }; }; development: { debug: boolean; useNullAsDefault: boolean; client: string; connection: { host: string; user: string; password: string; database: string; }; pool: { ...; }; migrations: { ...; }; }; production: { ...; }; }'.ts(7053)
```

========================================================

What am I doing wrong?
Please help.

Comment: `NODE_ENV` needs to be a subtype of `"local" | "development" | "production"`

Comment: @AluanHaddad How do I do that? I'm sorry, I'm still learning TypeScript. This is where I got `NODE_ENV`: 
`
export const {
  NODE_ENV = 'development',
  HOST = '0.0.0.0',
  PORT = 8081
} = process.env;
`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you can either supress these errors by setting:

```
  "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
```

in your `tsconfig.json`

or you can create an index signature for the `knexConfig` object in some way:

```
interface KnexConfig {
    [key: string]: object;
};

const knexConfig: KnexConfig = {
    local: {
        client: 'sqlite3',
        connection: {
        filename: './dev.sqlite3'
        }
    },

    development: {
        ...defaults,
        debug: true,
        useNullAsDefault: true
    },

    production: {
        ...defaults
    }
};
```

For more possibilities see the possible duplicate of this question: [How do I prevent the error "Index signature of object type implicitly has an 'any' type" when compiling typescript with noImplicitAny flag enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32968332/how-do-i-prevent-the-error-index-signature-of-object-type-implicitly-has-an-an)

Comment: In case anyone reads this, `Knex` (at least on version `^0.21.17`) has a `Config` typing: `import { Config } from 'knex'`

Answer (score 6):

For the future, at version ^1.0.4, knex export all types in Knex interface, so

```
import { Knex } from "knex";
```

and get the config autocomplete

```
module.exports = {
  client: "mysql",
  connection: {
    filename: path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "database", "connection.ts"),
  },
  migrations: {
    directory: path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "database", "migrations"),
  },
} as Knex.Config;
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually do it this way:

```
import Knex from 'knex'

type DbEnvironments = 'dev' | 'test' | 'stg' | 'prod'

const envs: Record<DbEnvironments, Knex.Config> = {
  dev: {
    client: 'pg',
    connection: {
      database: process.env.DATA_API_DB_NAME,
      host: process.env.DATA_API_DB_SERVICE_HOST,
      port: parseInt(process.env.DATA_API_DB_SERVICE_PORT),
      user: process.env.DATA_API_DB_USER || 'postgres',
      password: process.env.DATA_API_DB_PASSWORD || 'postgres',
    },
    migrations: {
      tableName: 'knex_migrations',
    },
    // debug: true,
  },
  ...
}

export default envs
```