# Update all attributes of a const object using a new object in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to update an object of type `IMessage` with a new object with the same type

```
interface IMessage {
  id: string,
  text: string,
  // and many more attributes
}

const message: IMessage = {
  id: "_id",
  text: "old text",
  // and many more attributes
}

const newMessage: IMessage = {
  id: "_id",
  text: "new text"
  // and many more attributes
}
```

I am expecting my `message` after updating will have value exactly the same with `newMessage`, but I cannot just reassign `message` object because `message` is declared as a `const`. This is what I have so far

```
const updateMessage = (message: any, newMessage: typeof message): void => {
    for (const attr in newMessage) {
        if (attr !== "id" && newMessage.hasOwnProperty(attr)) {
            message[attr] = newMessage[attr];
        }
    }
};
```

This function is working. But in this function, I have to declare `(message: any, newMessage: typeof message)`, otherwise Typescript will throw a warning `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'IMessage' has no index signature`. How can I make this function accept only arguments with type `IMessage`?

Comment: you can use spread operator `const updateMessage = { ...message, ...newMessage}` this will copy the properties of both objectcs in `updateMessage` it will override the properties of the first object with second

Comment: @ajuni880 I need to update attributes of `message`, not create a new object

Comment: and you can't declare `message` with `let`? You will be able to reassign

Comment: @ajuni880 that's the point. There are many reasons why I can't just declare `message` as `let`. One of those is you will violate the immutable rule. That's why I decided to use Typescript as the first place

Comment: ahh i understand. You can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32968332/how-do-i-prevent-the-error-index-signature-of-object-type-implicitly-has-an-an

Answer (score 2):

What are your thoughts on using [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)?  It copies all own and enumerable properties into its first argument, exactly as you seem to be doing.  There's a little hiccup with exempting `id` from that, but you can deal with that by using [rest object destructring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Rest_in_Object_Destructuring).  Like this:

```
const updateMessage = (message: IMessage, newMessage: IMessage): void => {
    const { id, ...nm } = newMessage; // make nm from newMessage without id prop
    Object.assign(message, nm); // update message with nm
};
```

This should behave like your original `updateMessage()` function without type errors.  Note that this isn't particularly type safe, since `Object.assign()`'s typing allows any arguments.  You could make your own typing which ensures that subsequent arguments don't add any unexpected properties, like this:

```
const safeAssign: <T>(target: T, ...args: Partial<T>[]) => T = Object.assign;

const updateMessage = (message: IMessage, newMessage: IMessage): void => {
    const { id, ...nm } = newMessage;
    safeAssign(message, nm);
};
```

But it behaves the same either way at runtime.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIFkIGctwOYoDeAUMmcsACYBcyWYUoeANKeZAB5i32MgtsyAeiHI4ISsgC24gJ7SA9lBRwwDYACMArpCzEAvsWIIFIetOy4CtDJfwoAvMhLkKNZACIA+lQ+tXnNyeCgA2koF+gsgiYhLScorKYmqM2roGRiZmYMggEADumDj2NkVWjs5RVLTeefmolJEBEFw1dcgRUTHikjIg8lJKKimaOtgGyJmm5rgwEACCOMB4ILQAPAAqAHwAFGBwUARBG8zIAHQXB3hYtAAKB2DAcCGbWwDaALoAlMgOW8gbX7IADyGgAVhAEGAznAlisANxTbLILQAB0oqggZXsQJ2Ujs1jQ2IIpzqxIgpQJEC+tAAbgoqL9-i5yFlzIQ3KcLmcQFJkPogWSqYjXLMFnCQHiqaSpF9EfpEcZpqEIGcQgo8FLigQ5cQ0RjIOSteVSQVybq2Sq1RrjfZdcQgA)

Answer (score 0):

U can use TS Generic types for this.

```
function updateMessage <T>(message: T, newMessage: T): void {
    for (const attr in newMessage) {
        if (attr !== "id" && newMessage.hasOwnProperty(attr)) {
            message[attr] = newMessage[attr];
        }
    }
};
```

Then pass the type when calling the function.

`updateMessage<IMessage>(message, newMessage)`

TS documentation about Generics: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

Comment: Your code's throwing a syntax error. It's because of the arrow function

Comment: That's right, edited answer to good old function. Does it work for you?