# TypeScript - ts(7053) : Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface

In TypeScript, I declare an interface like this:

```
export default interface MyDTO {
    readonly num: string;
    readonly entitle: string;
    readonly trb: string;
    readonly ucr: string;
    readonly dcr: string;
    readonly udm?: string;
    readonly ddm?: string;
}
```

With a function, I would like to access the value of a property, whose name is contained in a variable.

```
private doSomething(dto: MyDTO, property: string): any {
    let label: any;

    if (['dcr', 'ddm'].includes(property)) {
        label = doSomethingElse(dto[property]);
    } else {
        label = dto[property];
    }
    
    return label;
}
```

Unfortunately, TypeScript gives me the following error message :

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
> 'string' can't be used to index type 'MyDTO'.   No index signature
> with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type
> 'MyDTO'.ts(7053)

Anyone have an idea, please ?

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I prevent the error "Index signature of object type implicitly has an 'any' type" when compiling typescript with noImplicitAny flag enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32968332/how-do-i-prevent-the-error-index-signature-of-object-type-implicitly-has-an-an)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The reason for this is because `MyDTO` has explicitly named properties, but you're using a generic string as an index, so TypeScript is saying that it can't guarantee that whatever string is passed into your `doSomething` function will actually match a property name on your interface.

An excellent workaround for this that was introduced in TypeScript 2.1 is  `keyof`. This allows you to explicitly type something as a key of a certain class/interface.

This will A. get rid of the TS error you're seeing, and B. also check to make sure that any callers of your function actually pass a valid key.

```
export default interface MyDTO {
    readonly num: string;
    readonly entitle: string;
    readonly trb: string;
    readonly ucr: string;
    readonly dcr: string;
    readonly udm?: string;
    readonly ddm?: string;
}

function doSomething(dto: MyDTO, property: keyof MyDTO): any {
    let label: any;

    if (['dcr', 'ddm'].includes(property)) {
        label = doSomethingElse(dto[property]);
    } else {
        label = dto[property];
    }
    
    return label;
}

doSomething(obj, "foo") // is a TS error
doSomething(obj, "num") // is valid
```

Comment: Indeed this corrects me the case. But I have a somewhat special case, the value I have in property is not a key to my DTO. This can be a simple string that allows me to make an operation from the property of my DTO but I do not directly recover the property of my object. For example : if (property === 'test') { label = property.num + '-' + property.entitle; }. How to combine the keyof and the type string and that in the code of my function that does not concern me about the type?

Comment: I can do before a test on the type entered : if(typeof property === 'string').

Comment: How can I test if the value of property is a key to my object ? If I test the type of my object (type string), I always pass even if it is a key to my object.

Comment: @Answerrer I'm not sure I understand the question. Can you update your post with a full example of what is not working for you with this solution? It seems like you're wanting to know if the value of a property on your object is also a key to your object?

Comment: Saved my bacon. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 0):

@mhodges, with your suggestions, here is my modified function which seems to work well.
However in the following case, I had to add the "as string" otherwise I have the following error:

> Type 'string | keyof V 'cannot be used to index type' V'.ts (2536)

```
public getDefaultComparator(property: keyof V | string, v1: V, v2: V): number {
    let compareReturn = 0;
    if (v1.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
      const compareValue1 = v1[property as string];
      const compareValue2 = v2[property as string];
      if (compareValue1 > compareValue2) {
        compareReturn = 1;
      } else if (compareValue1 < compareValue2) {
        compareReturn = -1;
      }
    }

    return compareReturn;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Needed a simpler solution:

```
const key = property as keyof typeof MyDTO;
label = dto[key] ?? 'default value'
```

Followed Solution 1 from [here](https://www.totaltypescript.com/concepts/type-string-cannot-be-used-to-index-type).

Answer (score -16):

In the **tsconfig.json** file. **Set "strict": true --> false.**

This worked for me.

Comment: True, and I got the same error after creating a tsconfig.json file.. The default behavior is strict: true. But I guess setting it to false will just not shine light on the problem. Like out of view, out of problem. If you just want a quick and dirty fix for a small hobby or test, you could do this. But infact you have some problem on your logic.

Comment: Setting `strict` to `false` is not something that should be encouraged.