# Cannot properly index a type with Omit in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Consider a type:

```
interface Base {
  a: number;
  b: number;
  c: number;
}
```

Now consider a type derived from it where `c` is not present: `Omit<T, "c">`:

```
type MyType<T> = Omit<T, "c">;
```

Now consider that I need to browse through the keys of `A` and do stuff:

```
const value: MyType<Base> = {
  a: 34,
  b: 67,
};

for (const k in value) {
  const el = value[k]; // Error
}
```

An error is raised:

```
const value: Pick<Base, "a" | "b">
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Pick<Base, "a" | "b">'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Pick<Base, "a" | "b">'.ts(7053)
```

What is the best practice here?

Comment: Your interface was named BaseType, but you are using only Base in MyType generics. MyType<Base> -> MyType<BaseType> ?

Comment: Corrected, sorry

Comment: Follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62759505/typescript-ts7053-element-implicitly-has-an-any-type-because-expression)

Comment: @DanielFarina: Please post an answer, that fixed it, thanks

Comment: const el = value[k as keyof MyType];

Comment: Accepted answer in linked post is probably the easiest solution ( Dmitry Shapovalov mentioned this). I also updated some parts of my answer, in case you need other alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not related to `Omit` type. Try `for ... in` loop on any typed object, and you will have the same...

A kind of workaround is:

```
    for (const k in value) {
      const el = value[k as keyof typeof value]; 
    }
```

In this case you don't need to use `any` and you have your proper type in el - in this case `number`, but it will create a union type for all values in your interface.