# In TypeScript how can I handle for loops when using "import * as" syntax

Tags: typescript, import

In TypeScript I'd like to import all modules from a file and iterate over them, but the compiler throws an error at build time. Would someone know what settings or syntax I should use to fix this?

```
import * as dependencies from './dependencies';

for (const key in dependencies) {
  console.log(dependencies[key]());
}
```

At build time the compiler throws the below error:

```
error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'typeof import("/src/dependencies/index")'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'typeof import("/src/dependencies/index")'.
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": ["dom", "es2018"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2018",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "include": ["**/*.ts"]
}
```

**EDIT:**

As a workaround I'm doing something like this, but it seems redundant.

```
import * as dependencies from './dependencies';

interface Collection {
  [key: string]: any;
}

const dependencyCollection: Collection = dependencies;

for (const key in dependencyCollection) {
  console.log(dependencyCollection[key]());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a `for-in`, try using `Object.values` to convert it into an Iterable/Array so you can use `for-of`

```
import * as dependencies from './dependencies';

for (const dependency of Object.values(dependencies)) {
  console.log(dependency());
}
```

or if you also need the export name, use `Object.entries`

```
import * as dependencies from './dependencies';

for (const [key, dependency] of Object.entries(dependencies)) {
  console.log(key, dependency());
}
```

Comment: That's interesting @fregante - thank you, however I was hoping I wouldn't have to change the way I write JavaScript. The code I provided works in JavaScript but is not compiling from TypeScript and I was wondering why. Also, with my settings the code your provided resulted in the below compiler error. ```The left-hand side of a 'for...in' statement cannot be a destructuring pattern.ts(2491)```

Comment: I think you meant `for (const dependency of Object.entries(dependencies))`, but that throws a similar error.

Comment: To be clearer - I don't think I should need to tell TypeScript how to read a collection of imports. I feel like I'm missing a setting.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I meant to use `for-of`. I updated the answer. TypeScript does force you to adapt your code sometimes; "No index signature" is a [notorious](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32968332/288906) issue. IMHO [`for-in` should be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/288906) anyway, so it's not a bad situation.