# How do I prevent the error “Index signature of object type implicitly has an 'any' type” when compiling typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript1.8

I try to write some test unit with the following global variable

```
declare global{
  namespace NodeJS {
    interface Global {
      signin(): string;
    }
  }
}


global.signin = () => { 

  return ["test"] ;

};
```

I got error on the global.signin:

"Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'typeof globalThis' has no index signature."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I prevent the error "Index signature of object type implicitly has an 'any' type" when compiling typescript with noImplicitAny flag enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32968332/how-do-i-prevent-the-error-index-signature-of-object-type-implicitly-has-an-an)

Comment: `signin` returns `["test"]` which is `string[]`, not `string`. After fixing that, your code works just fine for me. I guess your real problem is somewhere outside the code you've shared.

Comment: Question arises though: Why do you need to make something global anyway? Why not some singleton service or something. Or Dependency Injection. There are many better ways to make something "global".

Comment: @funkizer adding sting[] doesn't change the error

Comment: @funkizer can you give me more information for better ways to do that?
I want to make the global for the test unit. To be able to use global.signin function