# Array in object with mat-Table in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

the table works almost well, the problem is that all the "**solde**" values ​​appear in the same column.

I want to display each balance and month value in a column, I tried to loop "**mnth**" but it doesn't work

this table is dynamically
how to display each **solde value** in a different column ?

```
export class visionCompacteDTOs {
    collaborator!:string;
    cetCP!:number;
    cetRTT!:number;
    perteRTT!:number;
    perteCP!:number;
    mnth:Month[]=[];
}

export class Month {
  month!: Date;
  solde!: number;
}
```

db.json :

```
{
    "visionCompacteDTO": [
        {
            "collaborator": "Jean",
            "cetCP": 0,
            "cetRTT": 0,
            "perteRTT": 3.56,
            "perteCP": 4,
            "mnth": [
                {
                 "month": "July",
                 "solde": 14.52
                },
                {
                 "month": "August",
                 "solde": 15.52
                },
                {
                 "month": "September",
                 "solde": 16.52
                },
                {
                    "month": "October",
                    "solde": 18.52
                },
                {
                    "month": "November",
                    "solde": 19.52
                },
                {
                    "month": "December",
                    "solde": 20.52
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

file.ts:

```
export class CompacteComponent {
  don: any;
  sld:any;
  userdata:any=[];
  constructor(private reportingService:ReportingService) { }

  columns: string[] = ['collaborator', 'cetCP', 'cetRTT', 'moisSoldes', 'perteRTT', 'perteCP','mnth'];
  index: string[] = ['collaborator', 'cetCP', 'cetRTT', 'moisSoldes', 'perteRTT', 'perteCP','mnth'];

  dataSource :visionCompacteDTOs[] = [];
  
  ngOnInit():void {
    
    this.reportingService.getNews().subscribe((response)=>{
      this.dataSource = response;
      console.log(response)
      for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        var username:any = this.dataSource[i].mnth;
        this.userdata = username;
        console.log(this.userdata);
        for (let j = 0; j < username.length; j++) {
          this.don = username[j].month;
          this.sld = this.userdata[j].solde;
          console.log(this.sld);
        }
      }
    },
    (error)=>{
      console.log("Error Occured: "+error);
    }
    )
  }

}
```

file.html :

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8 lftm">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="collaborator">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> </th>
    <td mat-row *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.collaborator}} </td>
  </ng-container>
  
  <ng-container matColumnDef="cetCP">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef > cetCP </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.cetCP}} </td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="cetRTT">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef > cetRTT </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.cetRTT}} </td>
  </ng-container>

   
  <ng-container  matColumnDef="mnth">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef >
      <span *ngFor="let solde of this.userdata"> {{solde.month}} </span></th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" >
      <span *ngFor="let loc of this.userdata"> {{loc.solde}}</span>  </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="perteRTT">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="prt"> Perte RTT </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.perteRTT}} </td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="perteCP">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="prt"> Perte CP </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.perteCP}} </td>
  </ng-container>
...
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Concept (in short)

**1.0** Retrieve first row's `mnth` and add into `displayedColumns` and `displayedMonthColumns` arrays.

**1.1** Add into `displayedColumns` for the columns must be existed and be required by `mat-header-row` and `mat-row`.

**1.2** Add into `displayedMonthColumns` for generating columns via `*ngFor`.

**2.1** Generate object (`mnthObj`) from `mnth` with `month` and `solde` as key value pair via `reduce`.

**3.1** Create new array result with existing `visionCompacteDTO` object and `mnthObj` via `map`.

---

### Solution

> .component.html

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8 lftm">
  ...

  <ng-container *ngFor="let month of displayMonthColumns">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="{{month}}">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{month}} </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[month]}} </td>
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
</table>
```

> .component.ts

```js
export class CompacteComponent implements OnInit {

  ...

  displayedColumns: string[] = [
    'collaborator',
    'cetCP',
    'cetRTT',
    'perteRTT',
    'perteCP'
  ];

  displayMonthColumns: string[] = [];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.reportingService.getNews().subscribe(
      (response: visionCompacteDTOs[]) => {
        if (!response) this.dataSource = response;

        for (let mnth of response[0].mnth) {
          this.displayedColumns.push(mnth.month);
          this.displayMonthColumns.push(mnth.month);
        }

        response = response.map(data => {
          let mnth = data.mnth;

          let mnthObj: { [key: string]: number } = mnth.reduce(function(
            obj: { [key: string]: number },
            item
          ) {
            obj[item.month] = item.solde;
            return obj;
          },
          {});

          return {
            ...data,
            ...mnthObj
          };
        });

        this.dataSource = response;
        console.log(response);
      },
      error => {
        console.log('Error Occured: ' + error);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

[Sample Solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gg1la1)

> Result

[image]

Comment: thank's for your answer, but it show me this error : Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'.

55             obj[item.month] = item.solde;

Comment: Hi updated my answer for the `noImpicitAny` fix. You may refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32968332/8017690).

Comment: thank's for first example it's work, but now i changed the db.json database(i added array in object month) and the model (visionCompacteDTOs ), do i have to do the same to display the table ? and thank's

Comment: Hi, I saw the response data structure changed quite a lot. I doubt the changes in the response data will break the current solution. Anyway, would suggest you to create another question **but not updating the current question** as the answer is designed based on the original question. Looking forward to your new question.

Comment: I want to replace the column perteRTT after the column September and the column perteCP after the column November, I can do this with *ngFor ?

Comment: Hi, you cannot re-positioning perteRTT and perteCP with `*ngFor` as the array used for holding and generating the month by sequence. Maybe you need to think to restructure your data and table.

Comment: unfortunately I did not find a solution