# Index error even after check it with in operator

Tags: typescript

I know I can't use a `string` as a object index because it's too unspecific and for that I should use `keyof` but I wondering why can't I use a `string` even after check it is a valid index with the `in` operator.

Example:

```js
if (fieldName in someObject) {
  const fieldValue = someObject[fieldName];
}
```

Typescript complain about this. I understand it can't compute the `fieldValue` type, but give an `any` type would be good enough.

Comment: Related (not duplicate): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32968332/how-do-i-prevent-the-error-index-signature-of-object-type-implicitly-has-an-an/58347263#58347263

Comment: @Marijn I'm using this approach to treat the error, but I can't undestande why there is the error in this situation

Answer (score 0):

Because typescript is complaining during compile time. When you are using `in` to check if a string is valid object key, it is doing it during run-time. As you might know, there is a difference between runtime and compile time. If you have used js, I think there would not be a problem, because it is not compiled language.
You can do something like `fieldName as keyof typeof someObject` telling ts during compile time that this is a valid object key, but this approach has some drawbacks.

Comment: I not sure if I have all knowledge about the diff between them, but what I was expecting is if TS, in a union type can compute all key of a element of the union after checking a prop that distinguish it, it could accept to use a string as index after checking it exists. Couldn't this assumption be made at compile time?

Comment: @DaniloMourelle did you define fieldName explicitly as a string? like const fieldName: string = 'someName';

Comment: Yes, is come from a parameter with string type, the same for the object that come with its type