# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type (key of forEach)

Tags: css, typescript

**Updated with missing headerStyles type**

Good day everyone. I've been trying to create a dynamic style adding function for table th elements:

```
type headerStyles = { textAlign: string; backgroundColor?: string };

const exampleData:[string, {
    textAlign: string;
    backgroundColor?: string;
}] = [
['header text1', { textAlign: 'left' }],
['header text2', { textAlign: 'center' }]
['header text3', { textAlign: 'left', backgroundColor: '#ddd' }]
['header text4', { textAlign: 'left' }]
]



const renderHeader = (headers: [string, headerStyles][]) => {
  const head = document.createElement('thead');
  const row = document.createElement('tr');
  headers.forEach(headerProps => {
    const th = document.createElement('th');
    const styles = headerProps[1];

    Object.keys(styles).forEach(prop => {
      th.style[prop] = styles[prop]; // <--- Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'headerStyles'
    });
  });
  ...
};
```

I've tried assigning `[prop as keyof typeof styles]` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57086672/element-implicitly-has-an-any-type-because-expression-of-type-string-cant-b), however it didn't help since some keys might be undefined (like `backgroundColor`).

Tried adding  `if (prop !== undefined)` check, which also didn't help.

Tried assigning `[key:string]` type [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32968332/how-do-i-prevent-the-error-index-signature-of-object-type-implicitly-has-an-an), however again, key might be undefined.

Is there any way without adding a bunch of empty `'backgroundColor` keys in data object?

Comment: You need to add `headerStyles` type definition to the example. In current form it is impossible to know the problem.

Comment: @ozm sorry, mistake while copying. Added missing type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way about it -

```ts
type HeaderStyles = {
    textAlign: string;
    backgroundColor?: string;
}

const exampleData: [string, HeaderStyles][] = [
    ['header text1', { textAlign: 'left' }],
    ['header text2', { textAlign: 'center' }],
    ['header text3', { textAlign: 'left', backgroundColor: '#ddd' }],
    ['header text4', { textAlign: 'left' }]
]



const renderHeader = (headers: [string, HeaderStyles][]) => {
    const head = document.createElement('thead');
    const row = document.createElement('tr');
    headers.forEach(headerProps => {
        const th = document.createElement('th');
        const styles = headerProps[1];

        (Object.keys(styles) as Array<keyof HeaderStyles>).forEach(prop => {
            const style = styles[prop];
            if (style) {
                th.style[prop] = style; // <--- Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'headerStyles'
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Here's a [playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NBB7gN).

Comment: omg, such a simple solution... I was so close :D thank you very much for the help.