# Strings array to object. Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'

Tags: typescript

Hi I ave a code like this:

```js
export type Options = Record<string, string>

export type CheckboxValue<T extends Options> = Partial<
    Record<keyof T, boolean>
>

export type Checkbox<T extends Options> = {
    value: CheckboxValue<T>
}
export function Checkbox<T extends Options>({
    value,
}: Checkbox<T>) {
    return value
}

export type FilterProps<T extends Options> = {
    options: T
    value: string[]
}

export function Filter<T extends Options>(
    props: FilterProps<T>,
) {
    const {  value = [] } = props

    const mappedValue = (() => {
        const contextValue: string[] = value

        const result = {}

        for (const item of contextValue) {
            /*
             * Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.
             *   No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'.(7053)
             */
            result[item] = true
        }

        return result
    })()

    return Checkbox({value: mappedValue})
}
```

Why does this happen and how to fix it?

[ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDyYYEsIDsDOcAvHAErADG0AJgDz4xRa4DmANHA06wHwBQfUJFgJkqAMIALSgGsARhBAA1AIYAbAK7BaAFTigYwXNUIZsefD2JwACithZ1tPnFdlKNWjOCIIAMzgdDgUINWAVXH5%20QXBoeCQUOClZBRBdfRBDY1NMHAIrEgBvFzcAN3UtAC4k6Qp5RVVNbR1%20AF8Y4Xg-DVwKc1walMV0gyMTdFyLHgAKYrc4cqa2Plbq5LrU3R4ASjg5tyhgGA0oAcWtFYEhONFEgDEsNUMoGygIMHwRzLGc-strfaud5-ao6Equc7AapcZgsADaAF1Lh0bt1ev04A8nsAoF8suMzHlLNNwXAwG8PtUsc9Xu9Pi1lrtAXAqAR4IUIRVUCREXBWtZyXSBPNWQw4ABbFRgFDURpaazTaa7IhWZkiizwVmGTJyqGcRiw3kkSHC%20ZuUXwQ74DRPAHtUnzPzQODTC1wLCGcVwfwsvDamC6pkOs2uAD0ACpgyG4OG4ABRMLiozwLDisBqLAUD1qRBwSQqQgROAAcgiiGLt1QckoKg0%20FQQit%20Dy3oCCVQxZhrArFAixfg1bgdeA1AQEHdxlAlZLhVaxYAdFGQ7HXAA5cfMahT5ssXAqY6HOAAdw9kjgKjJ9hUSeerennYN3ePBbgTp6o7w99nC%20mAHYAAwAKwAMzbEuZrhqG4EHMA1pPHCHrAOKCLWIwFzRnypohocB4DFaNowKSrTbEqWFwDhJwDOs9QgLMkLVJK0ojrqxGXEAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the index signature:

```
const result: { [key: string]: boolean } = {}
```

As to why it happens if I'd explain it most likely it wouldn't be accurate. Maybe TS docs could help you: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures

Update: This old SO thread could also be useful: [How do I prevent the error "Index signature of object type implicitly has an 'any' type" when compiling typescript with noImplicitAny flag enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32968332/how-do-i-prevent-the-error-index-signature-of-object-type-implicitly-has-an-an)